# Why does font size impact the height of my <li> elements?

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want to be able to specify the height of my "li" element for a horizontal list I'm making.  "line-height" and "height" have no impact on the visible height of the "li".  The only thing that changes the height of the "li" is changing the size of the font used within the "li".  This even happens when the "list-style" is set to "none".

What gives?

Comment: Can you show some code? Theres a few things that could be causing this. Applying height to your `<li>` tags should definately work.

Comment: Have you tried using the `display` property to change the display type of the `<li>` elements? For example to `inline-block`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `li` to `display: inline-block` or `float: left`.

`list-style` basically just determines the bullets to be used for the list, and doesn't really affect the inner elements otherwise.

Comment: Be aware that IE6 and IE7 only apply `display: inline-block;` to elements whose normal display value is `inline` - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Yes - `inline-block`, in my experience, really should only be reserved for when you want the horizontal list elements to be centered. In most cases `float: left` or `float: right` is the best (most compatible) option.

Comment: I should probably clarify - the elements will be centered with `inline-block` IF the parent element is set to `text-align: center`, otherwise not.

Comment: I understand how to horizontally align elements in on unordered list.  What I don't get is why the only way I can fix the height of the "li" element is by changing the font size. In reading about line-height, it states that it is a function of the font size, unless you specify px, em, etc... Even when I specify those, it still won't change the height unless I change the font size, and I'm not even using text in the list item.

Comment: @Tony: if you use `float` elements, you will be able to specify the height by either setting the `height` property, or by adding `padding` in combination with `font-size`. `line-height` is used for spacing lines in a paragraph, and therefore wouldn't have any effect on the actual height of the element (it can, however, have an effect on vertical positioning) if you have only one line.

Comment: @Tony - check it out in Firebug, then you'll be able to see what the computed height & line-height becomes -- and a nice picture of the final box model.

Comment: @Herman: I guess what I'm asking is if there's a way to NOT have the font size be a factor in setting the height of the list item?  Setting the "height" didn't do it for me.  As I am trying to vertically align the contents of the list items, manually using padding and font sizes is problematic.

Comment: @Tony: well, that's the point really, if you use `float`, you should be able to set the `height` property definitively. If not, post a link to a jsfiddle page so we might see what's going wrong.

Comment: This has been difficult to test because its in a web view on android right now.  I'm working on a phonegap project so firebug is out of the question unfortunately.  I'm gonna move another direction with this cause i cant justify anymore time on it.  Thank you very much everyone for the help and i'll be designating this answer as the right one since it contains tons of valid and useful info related to this subject.

Comment: line-height and font-size can affect the height of the li.  See http://moorer.me/mmKVHM.  But we still need to see all the CSS here to really address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
    height: 200px; /* as required */
}
```

The above is another method for getting list items to display inline, without using `display: inline;` which is a very restrictive property and should be applied sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 
`display:block` on the li

Comment: That will cause all of them to take up a whole line.

Answer (score 0):

- font-size could affect the computed height of an li element (depending on what's inside) IF line-height is proportional or relative AND no height is set on li (or li is display:inline).
- line-height could affect the computed height of an li element (depending on what's inside)  IF no height is set on li (or li is display:inline).
- height will affect the computed height of an li element if it's display:inline-block or display:block only (height has no effect at all on display:inline).

See http://moorer.me/mmKVHM for examples of how font-size and line-height can affect the height of li in different ways depending on the technique used.  The differences are somewhat obviated if a is set to display:block, so for example purposes I did not do so.

Others have already shared the two most common solutions to horizontal menus -- inline-block or floated blocks.  Inline can be used, but likely won't give you the control you need.